# When backtracking is necessary?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, backtracking

For example the following two questions about DFS a binary tree, why the first one need back tracking(delete the last element in the working set every time whenever hit a leaf node), and the other one do not? They both asked for all the paths meet the requirement, not trying to find whether a path exist or not, since the path is already reached to an end when hit a leaf, in order to format other possible path shouldn't we back track to the last node we visit?

https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/

https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/

Answer for first question:

```
 public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
     List<List<Integer>> finalResult=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
     List<Integer> tempResult = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     pathSumHelper(root,sum,tempResult,finalResult);
     return finalResult;
 }
 public void pathSumHelper(TreeNode node, int sum, List <Integer> tempResult, List<List<Integer>> finalResult){
     if(node == null) return;
     sum -= node.val;
     if( node.left == null && node.right == null ){  
        if( sum == 0){
          tempResult.add(node.val);
          finalResult.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(tempResult));
          tempResult.remove(tempResult.size() -1);
        }
     return;
     }
     tempResult.add(node.val);
     pathSumHelper(node.left, sum, tempResult, finalResult);
     pathSumHelper(node.right, sum, tempResult, finalResult);
     tempResult.remove(tempResult.size() -1 );
 }
```

Answer for the second question:

```
 public List<String> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode root) {
    List<String> finalResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tempResult = "";
    findPath(root, tempResult, finalResult);
    return finalResult;
 }

 public void findPath(TreeNode node, String tempResult, List<String> finalResult){
    if( node == null ){
        return;
    }
    if(node.left == null && node.right == null){
        tempResult += String.valueOf(node.val);        
        finalResult.add(tempResult);
        // why no delete last integer added in tempResult before return?
        return;
    }
    tempResult += String.valueOf(node.val);
    findPath(node.left, tempResult+"->", finalResult);
    findPath(node.right, tempResult+"->", finalResult);
    // same, why no delete last integer added in tempResult before return?               
 }
```

Comment: Based on my answer to your question, I think you should also add **java** as a tag to this question as the question you asked is quite related to the language you used and your programming in it. I would add it myself but I'd have to remove one of the tags you added. It's better if you choose of which one to let go.

Comment: Hi ilim, that's a great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second algorithm, when you make a recursive call to `findPath`, you are using + operator, while passing `tempResult` + "->" as an argument. **+** operator causes a concatenation which creates a new `String` object. Basically at each level of recursion, you pass along a fresh `String` object to the lower levels, and leave `tempResult` variable of each level out of the reach of lower levels.

Consequently, you actually do not have access to the `String` object of the upper levels of recursion and even if you backtracked, it would only update the `String` object passed to that level of recursion and not the `tempResult` belonging to an upper level, which was never chanced to begin with! That's why backtracking is not necessary in the second solution, and is therefore not done.